# How to get the Message on StatusCodes.Status204NoContent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I have this in my controller:

[

```
HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateCalendarEntry(CalendarEntry model)
        {
            try
            {
                model.LabelColor = "blue";
                var result = await repo.AddCalendarEntry(model);
                if(result == null)
                {
                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent, "Cannot Do It!");
                }
                return apiResult.Send200(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return apiResult.Send400(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

I get the response in my Service in Blazor WASM like so:

```
using var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // auto logout on 401 response
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                navigationManager.NavigateTo("login");
                return default;
            }

            if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                await helperService.InvokeAlert("Bad Request", $@"{response.ReasonPhrase}", true);
            }

            if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
            {
                var x = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                await helperService.InvokeAlert("Bad Request", $@"{response.ReasonPhrase}", true);
            }

            // throw exception on error response
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //var error = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Dictionary<string, string>>();
                //throw new (error["message"]);

                return default;
                //throw new ApplicationException
                //    ($"The response from the server was not successful: {response.ReasonPhrase}, " +
                //    $"Message: {content}");
            }
```

I need to get the reply from the controller on "No Content" the message "Cannot Do It!". I am trying the ReasonPhrase, but I don't know how to put the error there.

Comment: You can use `ObjectResult` and set status code manually

Comment: @AndriyShevchenko, could you show me how Sir?

Comment: "A 204 response is terminated by the first empty line after the header fields because it cannot contain a message body." according to [this](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#status.204)

Comment: 204 is a success indicator, with no additional information returned, so the way the OP tries to use it here makes no sense in relation to how the protocol is defined. -- Perhaps he should return a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return any value when you retun NoContext response. This is the only way I see to add your message to a response header. This code was tested using VS

```
....
 if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
 {
   var reason= response.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h=> h.Key=="Reason");
   if(reason!=null)
    await helperService.InvokeAlert("Bad Request", $@"{reason.Value}", true);
 }
 .....
```

action

```
HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateCalendarEntry(CalendarEntry model)
 {
            .....
  if(result == null)
  {
 HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Reason", "Cannot Do It!");
return NoContent();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Warning, not tested.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateCalendarEntry(CalendarEntry model)
{
      try
      {
            model.LabelColor = "blue";
            var result = await repo.AddCalendarEntry(model);
            if(result == null)
            {
                 return new ObjectResult("Cannot Do It!")
                 {
                      StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent
                 };
            }
            return apiResult.Send200(result);
      } 
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
            return apiResult.Send400(ex.Message);
      }
}
```